# Install tcl 8.5 Fedora 22

Tags: installation, tcl, fedora

I want install the specific version 8.5 of Tcl in Fedora 22.
I executed:

```
dnf install tcl
```

but I found only the 8.6 version.
I tried `dnf install tcl-8.5`, `… tcl8.5` or `… libtcl8.5` but nothing...
How I can request a specific version of Tcl?

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need a specific version of Tcl and it isn't in any of the RPM mirrors, you can always just build a copy from source. Tcl has very few external dependencies (deliberately) and it is designed to be easy to install somewhere like `/usr/local`.

The definitive source release is current done via [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/8.5.19/) and 8.5.19 is the currently recommended release from the 8.5 release stream. Though in general we actually recommend upgrading software to use 8.6, we can totally understand why you wouldn't if you're just trying to get some other software operational and 8.5 is still fully supported.

Once you've unpacked the source release, just change into the `unix` directory within it and do `./configure && make && sudo make install` (the default installation location for source releases is `/usr/local`, which should be fine for you). You'll need a C development environment like gcc installed, but the usual RPM for that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`tcl-8.5` was never build for Fedora 22, as you can check in [koji (build system)](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=611). The oldest version for Fedora 22 is `tcl-8.6.1-6.fc22`, but you would probably have to download it manually, because it is probably not anymore on the mirrors.

The other possibility is to download sources and build it from sources, basically install `fedpkg` and do:

```
fedpkg clone -a tcl
cd tcl
git checkout f20         # Fedora 20 is the last one having version 8.5
fedpkg local
```

it will produce RPMs with this version, you can install later on using `dnf downgrade` or so.